# How can I format my SQL output to match my GraphQL type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I've had a google for this, but can't seem to find the answer.

I have a GraphQL type that looks like this:

```
type Ticket {
    id: Int!
    bandID: Int!
    band: Band
    ticketURL: String!
    price: Int!
    date: String!
  }
```

I'd like to be able to return something like this from MSSQL, GraphQL and JS:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    ticketURL: "https://example.co.uk",
    price: 50,
    date: "2019/01/01",
    band: {
     id: 1,
     name: "Band name"
    }
  }
]
```

What would be the most efficient way of returning a data structure like this? The first thing that comes to mind is something like the below, but it seems *so* inefficient and wrong.

```
// Call SQL to get all tickets: "SELECT * FROM Ticket"
// For each ticket
  // Call SQL to get the Band
  // Merge with the ticket obj
```

Comment: This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow I'm afraid. You either need to write this interface yourself or use one of the libraries out there that can do some mapping between GraphQL and a database (there are a couple, including one I've been working on that is on GitHub if you want some ideas)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I would encourage you not to shoot for what you're describing. The designing principles of the GraphQL spec encourage you to make sure that your API logic is specifically for your client's wants, and that if something better-suited to your needs comes along to replace GraphQL, you should be able to remove the GraphQL layer and replace it with whatever the new thing is without having to rewrite your logic. This specific request is, according to the GraphQL inventors, too tightly-coupled to the API. For most people, the latency to the database isn't a big enough bottleneck to need this kind of optimization. Instead, I would encourage you to use dataloaders (for caching and for bulk requests) and just to write your resolvers to call your ORM or whatever to fetch these data points.